# How to send datafrom one activity to another in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

My app has 2 activites.

1. The first activity is just a simple form where a user enters course information(class title, professor..etc.) the first activity passes the data which is supposed to be stored in a list.
2. In the second activity. The problem is that only the first course gets stored in the list, after the first time nothing new gets added to the second activity.

How can i do this ?

Comment: How about you post some relevant code? Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: please post your code that helps alot to give u as an appropriate ans thanks :)

Comment: here is a good example about how to switch between activities and send data between them : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/117/how-to-switch-between-different-activities-in-android/

Answer (score 5):

In your first activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("login", jObj.getString(KEY_LOGIN));
                            intent.putExtra("mdp", jObj.getString(KEY_MDP));
                            intent.putExtra("prenom", jObj.getString(KEY_PRENOM));
                            intent.putExtra("nom", jObj.getString(KEY_NOM));
                            intent.putExtra("mail", jObj.getString(KEY_MAIL));
                            intent.putExtra("tel", jObj.getString(KEY_TEL));
                            startActivity(intent);
```

In your second activity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

          if (intent != null) {
              login = intent.getStringExtra("login");
              mdp = intent.getStringExtra("mdp");

              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("login"));
              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("prenom"));
              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("nom"));
              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("mail"));
              items.add(intent.getStringExtra("tel"));
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can pass data from one `Activity` to another with an `Intent` like this:

In your first Activity:

```
// Create your Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class);

// Now you can add extras to the intent, you identify extras with a String key
intent.putExtra("text", someString);
intent.putExtra("amount", someInteger);

// Then you start your Activity with this Intent
startActivity(intent);
```

In your second Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Only get data from Intent when the Activity is new
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // Now you read the values from the Intent
        String someString = intent.getStringExtra("text");

        int someInteger = intent.getIntExtra("amount", 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hey its simple look at the code

for sending

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Confirmation.class)  
i.putExtra("name",etName.getText().toString()));
i.putExtra("pass",etPass.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

for recieving in next activity

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                  String strEmployeeID="";
                  if (extras != null)
                  {

                      String value = extras.getString("name");
                              String value1 = extras.getString("pass");
    //                
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      strEmployeeID = value;
                               strEmployeePass = value1;
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send data between two Activities .You must call following one,

```
 startActivityForResult(getcontext(), SecondActivity.class);
```

On calling this,Activity starts the second.In turn, second response to this intent and reply back with necessary data.

```
 public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) {
        if (mParent == null) {
            Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar =
                mInstrumentation.execStartActivity(
                    this, mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), mToken, this,
                    intent, requestCode, options);
            if (ar != null) {
                mMainThread.sendActivityResult(
                    mToken, mEmbeddedID, requestCode, ar.getResultCode(),
                    ar.getResultData());
            }
            if (requestCode >= 0) {

                mStartedActivity = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (options != null) {
                mParent.startActivityFromChild(this, intent, requestCode, options);
            } else {
                // Note we want to go through this method for compatibility with
                // existing applications that may have overridden it.
                mParent.startActivityFromChild(this, intent, requestCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Following one you must call this on the First Activity (from where the intent called).It helps to recieves the reply data from second Activity.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(!isFeatureInstalled(getContext()))
            return;

        if(requestCode == GET_REMINDER_DETAILS && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            mFilled = true;
            fillDataFromIntent(data);
            checkALertRequired.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just simply do it like that:

passing data from 1st activity to 2nd activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourafirstctivity.this,Yoursecondactivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("yourkey", yourvalue);
       intent.putExtra("yourkey", yourvalue);
       intent.putExtra("yourkey", yourvalue);
       startActivity(intent);
```

and get the data from 1st activity to 2nd activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);


String yourstring = getIntent().getExtras().getString("yourkey");
String yourstring = getIntent().getExtras().getString("yourkey");
String yourstring = getIntent().getExtras().getString("yourkey");

}
```